# Access file of a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster with multiple nodes and i also have created a persistent volume in order to have persistence of my data in a Pod. What i am actually looking for is the following:

Lets say that we have a pod, named pod1 that is connected with the Persistent Volume and in a specific directory we have some files. If i have another different pod, named pod2 which is in the same node with the pod1, that wants to copy a file from the directory of the pod1 which is connected with the PV.

Is there any right way to configure this?

Comment: Not fully understood where exactly pod2 wants to put the file. But I think you have to connect pod2 to the same persistent volume as pod1 for this

Comment: Imagine that the pod1 has a json file with some data and pod2 has a code which needs these data in order to make some computations. So the pod2 needs to find a way to have access in this json file in order to continue with the computation.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a shared persistent volume mounted in both pods.
You can achieve this in a couple of different ways:

- Use a `hostPath` volume pointing to the same directory.
- Use a volume type that supports RWX (read write many) [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).